# jquery select value of child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my html, I'm trying to grab the value of '**link**'

```
<li class="nav-parent nav-expanded">
   <a>
   <i class="licon-layers" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   <span>Virtual Servers</span>
   </a>
   <ul id="vms" class="nav nav-children" style="">
      <li value="0">
         <a link="i-2-20-VM">puppet-srv2</a>
      </li>
      <li value="0">
         <a link="i-2-18-VM">puppet-srv1</a>
      </li>
      <li value="0">
         <a link="i-2-24-VM">testing</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
```

Here Is what I have tried so far, but it isn't working:

```
$("#vms").on("click", "li", function() {
   var href = $(this).children('a').find('link').attr();
    console.log(href);
});
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, your help is highly appreciated

Comment: Is that even valid <a> tag syntax? [This](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) does not like "link" as being a valid attribute. You might want to use "href" instead.

Comment: I'm using that just to hold value of VM name, later I will use $.post to send it to backend file.

Comment: It sounds like it'd be more appropriate to turn this into a data attribute (e.g. "data-vm") Then you could just use jQuery's .data() function.

Comment: I didn't know that was possible, I will experiment with it, thanks for your input

Comment: np. "data" also has the effect of being an HTML5 standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You trying to find attribute link using `.find('link')` code. Since the child element already founded, then just capture it attribute using `.attr()`. Instead of that, try following code:

**Change this:**

```
var href = $(this).children('a').find('link').attr();
```

**into**

```
var href = $(this).children('a').attr('link');
```

**or you can use code below also:**

```
$("#vms").on("click", "li", function() {
  var href = $(this).find('a').attr('link');
   console.log(href);
});
```

**AND i read your comment that sound :**

> I'm using that just to hold value of VM name

If so, you can add data attribute for user defined attribute like below :

```
<a data-link="i-2-20-VM">puppet-srv2</a>
```

Then to get it value, just use the [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) function like below:

```
var href = $(this).find('a').data('link');
```